# test localhost website compatibility online, on older browsers

Tags: html, cross-browser

I'm implementing a web application that uses html5 features.

Is still on localhost. Is there any online service that I can test my localhost site somehow?

I mean, is there an online service that simulates mobile browsers, or versions of older web browsers?

So I don't have to download/install older browsers?

Comment: Yes there are services that do that (http://browsershots.org/ could be one). But not from your localhost because that is not (by default) publicly visible.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a browser named Lunascape, because its giving you facility to run your site (local and live both) on different 3 rendering engine in same single browser. 
And we know that almost all browser uses one of these three rendering engine.

Trident = for IE,Internet Explorer Mobile version and [others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_%28layout_engine%29)

Gecko = Firefox, Firefox for mobile and many  [others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_%28layout_engine%29)

Webkit = Safari, chrome... [know more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit)

so you can just switch to any one of these three rendering engine by click on icon at right side of address bar of lunascape browser.

Download and check it. May be it useful to you...[Lunascape](http://www.lunascape.tv/)

Click here for [More information about Lunascape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunascape)

In other option, [Avant](http://www.avantbrowser.com/) browser is also good choise. but I like Lunascape more compare to avant, but that is my personal opinion may be you have different experience with one of these two.

Because Adobe Browser lab is shutdown you can also go with [BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com/start?cbsid=browserlab) or [Saucelab](https://saucelabs.com/) but these are paid.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a firefox or chrome plugin (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/test-ie/eldlkpeoddgbmpjlnpfblfpgodnojfjl):
here are a list of services and plugins:
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/complete-guide-to-cross-browser-compatibility-check/

Answer (score 1):

Install [Test IE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/test-ie/?src=ss) plugin to Firefox and then run your local site and click to Test IE icon on the right-top of Firefox and choose which version of IE you want.  [image: Test IE icon]

Note:It has 30 minutes free trial time.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Thanks @hipkiss. BrowserStack has changed add on name as Test IE, i fixed url.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question today and a coworker told me about [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/). Create a free online account and then install the chrome extension. Fairly easy setup -> Just make sure to click Yes when they ask if you want to do local testing, and it'll guide you through getting started.

The testing options are extremely detailed: I'm using it to check between a Chrome on Mac vs Chrome on Windows styling bug, and it's working perfectly for testing my localhost dev version.